# Preencher um listbox com predicate<string>

Tags: c#, delegate

Estou estudando DDD e WebAPI e à medida que vou encontrando dificuldades, vou pesquisando e tentando resolver. Claro, que à s vezes me deparo com coisas simples para alguns aqui e não consigo resolver de imediato.

Às vezes até entendo o que tem que ser feito, mas não sei como fazer, como é o caso agora. Com projeto Console, eu fiz, mas troquei para um Windows Form e estou tendo essa dificuldade.

Preciso preencher um ListBox, como resultado de um Foreach lambda resultante de uma lista de um Predicate. A questão está no ForEach, assim:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string[] teste = new string[] { "um", "dois", "tres", "quatro", "cinco" };
    Predicate<string> p = objetoTeste => objetoTeste.Length >= 4;

    var i = from items in teste
            where (p(items))
            select (items);

    i.ToList().ForEach(listBox1.Items.Add()**==>> Dúvida aqui**);

    /*foreach (var item in teste)
    {
        listBox1.Items.Add(item);
    }*/
}
```

A questão é como chamar o `ListBox1.Items.Add()` e preenchê-lo dentro do `foreach`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assim

```
i.ToList().ForEach(item => listBox1.Items.Add(item));
```

Se o parâmetro do método `Add` for do mesmo tipo de `item` (string, neste caso) ainda dá pra fazer mais simples

```
i.ToList().ForEach(listBox1.Items.Add);
```

[Veja funcionando .NET Fiddle.](https://dotnetfiddle.net/Zlx75v)